# How to handle Illegal Chars in XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, encoding

> How should I handle this situation?

I set the Encoding to UTF8 but I still get errors...

[image]

I create that string (that I set to the `WebBrowser.DocumentText`) from a `MemoryStream` object and I'm ending it like this:

```
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[ms.Length];
buffer = ms.ToArray();
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the XML string as a *filename*.

You probably want to write

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, wb.DocumentText);
```

Or, alternatively,

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.OpenFile(), false, Encoding.UTF8)) {
    write.Write(wb.DocumentText);
}
```